# How to convert all shapefiles in folder into KML using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, kml, error-000732

I was trying to convert all the shp in a folder into kml.

> featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
>
> for fc in featureclasses:
>
> ```
>  # Set Local Variables
>
>  composite = 'COMPOSITE'
>
>  pixels = 1024
>
>  dpi = 96
>
>  clamped = 'CLAMPED_TO_GROUND'
>
>  scale = 1
>
>  outKML = fc[:-4] + ".kmz"
>
>  arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion(fc,outKML, scale, composite,'', pixels, dpi, clamped)
> ```

It always says
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Layer: Dataset ZZZ.shp does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (LayerToKML).

But I can manually do it within ArcMap 10.1 Desktop...

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, are you defining an workspace directory before your loop?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I looks that is not the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the Layer to KML tool takes either LAYERS (feature layers in a map for example), or LAYER FILES (.lyr files on disk pointing at featureclasses).

If you want to run this as a script outside of ArcMap you'll have to run MakeFeatureLayer on every shapefile, turning them into a layer first and pass that onto Layer to KML.

This is starter code...you'll have to modify it to make unique names. As-is it'll overwrite each KMZ it outputs.

```
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in featureclasses:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "name1")
    arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion("name1", r"c:\temp\foo1.kmz")
```

Comment: I added MakeFeatureLayer on every shapefile, but the same error was raised.

Comment: I added code. It should be enough to get you started